Spring boot + Angular application cannot stream video
I have created an application with JHipster (Spring Boot + Angular) and I would like to play some mp4 videos in a browser.
However, it always ends in downloading the full file before playing it, even though I would like that the video starts as soon as possible and then continue to download in the background.
My code in the back-end:
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> getVideo(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers,
                                                       Principal principal) throws IOException {
        Optional<Video> video = videoService.findOne(id, user);

        if (video.isEmpty()) {
            log.debug("Video not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource(video.orElseThrow().getFileLocation());

        List<HttpRange> httpRanges = headers.getRange();
        if (httpRanges.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "video/mp4")
                .body(fileSystemResource);
        }

        HttpRange httpRange = httpRanges.get(0);
        long fileLength = fileSystemResource.contentLength();
        long start = httpRange.getRangeStart(fileLength);
        long end = httpRange.getRangeEnd(fileLength);

        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_RANGES, "bytes");
        responseHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf((end - start) + 1));
        responseHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_RANGE, "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + fileLength);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT)
            .headers(responseHeaders)
            .body(fileSystemResource);
    }

Front-end:
<video #videoPlayer controls controlslist="nodownload noplaybackrate" width="800" height="800" preload="metadata" volume>
    <source [src]="videoUrl()" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support this video file.
  </video>

videoUrl = signal('');

  constructor() {
    this.activatedRoute.data.pipe(takeUntilDestroyed()).subscribe(data => {
      this.videoUrl.set(data['video']);
    });

}

Do you see the issue?
There are different questions about how to stream a video, and I have tried all the various options (e.g. with and without autoplay, with and without preload, I have checked the headers, etc.)

Could it be https://superuser.com/questions/1753260/what-makes-a-mp4-streamable ?

Very good suggestion @SotiriosDelimanolis , I missed that question. However, I have my metadata at the beginning of the file and the audio is interleaved with the video (I checked the first one with AtomicParsley and the second with ffprobe). So, it should be ok

not sure what your angular code is doing there, but make sure the src isn't processed through angular... (just a URL to the resource/endpoint)

@browsermator It returns something like: blob:http://localhost:9000/1fdb4297-738e-412c-b070-bc53fd5dd343, is it bad?

probably... seems like you should be returning a file.  Avoid any JS processing here... the src should be to an endpoint that returns a file.  You could also make the SRC go directly to a file, but it depends on whether you want to allow deep-links or want to authenticate the user before serving the file.

I want to authenticate before @browsermator and I am not sure how to do it (I am using a bearer token in the rest of the application)

that might require a cookie be set when you first get the token.   Then have your endpoint check for it.  I would test without the authorization first, just to be sure this is not a backend problem.  Ultimately the backend has to stream that file.

Not sure JS processing has anything to do with the problem (though if you do that you slow it down a bit since you're creating a copy)  Look into using MediaSource so that you can buffer the bytearray:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource

Does this simplified code show any playback (without needing a full download first)?
//HttpRange httpRange = httpRanges.get(0);
long fileLength = fileSystemResource.contentLength();
long start = 0;
long end = (fileLength - 1);

HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_RANGES, "bytes");
responseHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf((end - start) + 1));
responseHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_RANGE, "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + fileLength);

